# How to get a file using fetch in 'Code by Zapier'

Tags: zapier

I was requesting an API that delivers pdf. This also need authorization.

```
var fileUlr = 'https://api.safetyculture.io/audits/1234/exports/5678.pdf';

var getFile = fetch( fileUlr, { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer 2034weoiroew' } } )
        .then( function( fileBinary ) {
            return fileBinary;
        });
```

I am getting the file in binary format. How to convert this to original pdf? Then I need to programmatically upload the file to dropbox/google drive. Can you help me?